# Uploading a file html/php

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I'm currently trying to upload a csv file to a database through simple html and then php. My problem is I like to know how things work/what's actually happening (I guess that's why I have so many questions)

So anyway my HTML is as follows:

```
<html>
<form action="mysite.php" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Now upload it!">
</form>
</html>
```

My PHP is just:

```
<?php
echo 'Success';
?>
```

Before I actually store the file in a database of my liking where is the file actually stored?

Is it created as a temp file on the server?
Saved on the server ram?
Does it not actually do anything since it's not told to do anything (aka: save to DB)

Thanks

Comment: Well,so far it does really nothing (literally), starting from the missing "multipart/form-data" form encoding needed when uploading a file. You should research a bit on the proceeding, start from here :http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: It's not even uploading a file at this point. You need the correct enctype. `<form [SIC] enctype="multipart/form-data">`. After you get that sorted, I'd suggest doing a `print_r($_FILES);` in your receiving script to see how the information is posted.

Comment: use a `print_r( $_FILES );` in your mysite.php file, and I think you'll be able to move forward.

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you are trying to import this CSV file into your database for use as a database table, or if you are just wanting to store the file itself.

Comment: Right now I just want to store the file itself. I will go into storing it into a DB later. Thanks for the responses. After I get some time to look into all of the links you guys posted, I will select which one I feel is best. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would be in a temp file on the server but in your case it wouldn't because you missed the encoding type :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
```

Here's the manual on file uploading [php file uploading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

You can see what is uploaded by doing a var_dump($_POST) for variable names and var_dump($_FILES) for file data to help understand.

As you can see in the reference once the file is uploaded you need to move it from its temp location to its final destination.

Comment: Hit it dead on. It's not even a temp file yet because of the missing encoding type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Essentially, the file is uploaded via HTTP, and php stores it in a temporary file on the server.

You can get a handle on that temporary file using the global `$_FILES` array.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload file it is stored on the server, after that if you want to import this CSV to database you must use php script to parse ([CSV Parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/)) it and insert in DataBase. Or if you want to store only the file path, not the data from CSV then you must store only file path in DataBase.

Answer (score 0):

The file is stored temporarily as long as the script is running. The information can be found in $_FILES.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be stored to a temporary file on the server, and you can find out information about it using the `$_FILES` superglobal. You can start out by changing your script to dump out the superglobal to see what's inside:

```
<?php 
print_r($_FILES); 
?>
```

PHP provides a selection of useful functions to deal with file uploads, and you should use these rather than just reaching into the filesystem - remember that any file upload counts as user input and therefore becomes a security risk! You should start by checking if the file is the one you're looking for:

```
$filename = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
if (!is_uploaded_file($filename)) {
    // error
}
```

And you can use the `move_uploaded_file()` function to stick the file somewhere more convenient:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], '/more/useful/path') {
    // all good
}
```

Finally you should remember that not just the file itself, but the filename and the filesize reported, are user-submitted data, and make sure to sanitise these appropriately before use.

There's a tonne of handy stuff here: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php